# Ubuntu One in startup applications

Tags: ubuntu-one

Accidentally, removed the entry from "ubuntu one" entry from the startup applications, means I wont automatically get synced on startup.

Please help.

Goto your **system > preferences > startup applications** 
Now look for the entry saying 'Ubuntu One'. click edit from the right pane, you'll see the command there. Kindly tell me that command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`/bin/sh -c '[ -d "$HOME/Ubuntu One" ] && ubuntuone-launch'`

Answer (score 4):

The starting up disconnected is a known bug, which is fixed in maverick-proposed already. Until you get that fix you can ask it to connect "manually" via the preferences app, or by entering `u1sdtool --connect` from a terminal.

Answer (score 2):

The first answer is the correct command, if you re-add the start up entry as:

Name: `Ubuntu One`

Command: `/bin/sh -c '[ -d "$HOME/Ubuntu One" ] && ubuntuone-launch'`

Save it and log out and in again, Ubuntu one will be functioning again.

Comment: does it have a single quote at the end '

Answer (score 0):

```
/bin/sh -c '[ -d "$HOME/Ubuntu One" ] && ubuntuone-launch'
```